# Why does the documentation on some languages say "equivalent to" rather than "is"?

Tags: c++, python, documentation, compiler

Why does the documentation on some languages say "equivalent to" rather than "is"?

For example, [the Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?#itertools.chain) say

> `itertools.chain(*iterables)`
>
> ...
>
> **Equivalent** to:
>
> ```
> def chain(*iterables):
>     # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
>     for it in iterables:
>         for element in it:
>             yield element
> ```

Or [this C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) on `find_if`:

> The behavior of this function template is **equivalent** to:
>
> ```
> template<class InputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
>   InputIterator find_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred)
> {
>   while (first!=last) {
>     if (pred(*first)) return first;
>     ++first;
>   }
>   return last;
> }
> ```

If that's not the actual code, can't they post it? And if it is the actual code, why do they have to say it's "Equivalent" rather than simply "is"?

Comment: Note that what you see for `find_if` is **not** "the" documentation for C++. If it was, then the cast to `bool` (which you see in the answer below) would be wrong.

Comment: In the case of python if you look for the source code you'll find that `chain` is implemented directly in C, thus it is "equivalent" to that python code because it produces the same result, but it avoids a bit of overhead of interpreting that bytecode.

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm aware it's not the official documentation, its just the resource I've found most helpful in finding out the particulars of C++

Comment: They'd be forced to use whatever approach was set in the standard, even if a significantly better one was available.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Because the standard writers don't want to actually assert an implementation.  They want to define what it *does*, but not necessarily how it does it.  So, for example, if you look at the [GNU C++ version of `find_if`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01347.html), you will see that the implementation is slightly different from what you give, which is based on the C++ standard:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
inline _InputIterator
__find_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
    _Predicate __pred, input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (__first != __last && !bool(__pred(*__first)))
     ++__first;
       return __first;
}
```

This is functionally equivalent to what the standard has, but not exactly the same.  This gives compiler writers flexibility.  There may be a better way to do it  for a particular platform.  The implementor may wish to use a different coding style.

This is particularly true for scripting languages like python in that the implementor may decided to implement in a completely different language for performance reasons.  Someone implementing python may, for instance, write `itertools.chain(*iterables)` in C++.  This is perfectly fine if the standard says "equivalent to" as long as the code does the same as the provided python.  If the standard said "is" instead, then implementors would be required to either implement in that language, or not meet the standard.

In summary:

1. Because they don't want to prevent an implementation from writing better code than the standard provided
2. Because they don't want to prevent an implementation from using an entirely different language, to improve performance

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening answer! I suspected the answer was something along those lines.

Comment: @lerenard, you may find it further enlightening to read the full implementation of find_if from Steven's link. (What's he's got there is really just an excerpt.)

Comment: @WinstonEwert, Unfortunately I'm not quite at the level of fully understanding code like that, but the liberal use of underscores is certainly a point of interest!

Comment: @lerenard: Those additional leading underscores are there so that the standard library internals don't interfere with the code you might write (names with double leading underscores are reserved for use by the compiler/standard library writers).

Comment: This sort of thing happens all the time in Java too, as both runtime optimisations and intrinsified method calls can cause a different implementation to be run without warning (and hopefully without any noticeable effects to the calling code).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Not just leading, actually. The full rule is: "contains two consecutive underscores, or starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter." Additionally, names starting with an underscore a reserved in the global namespace.

Comment: Well, in C and C++, there's always the as-if-rule, so even if the standard said is instead of equivalent to, the actual implementation might differ.